# Table-valued parameter READONLY error on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I have user-defined table type and stored procedute that uses this type

```
create type dbo.ut_Type1(
        Col1 varchar(10),
        Col2 varchar(10),
        Col3 int) 
go
create procedure dbo.p_Procedure1(
        @TVP ut_Type1 READONLY,
        @Year int,
        @ID int)
as
begin
```

This is calling from client application

```
var td:TMSTableData;

......

TMSQuery1.SQL.Text:='exec dbo.p_Procedure1 @TVP = :Par1, @Year = :Par2, @ID = :Par3';
TMSQuery1.ParamByName('Par1').AsTable:=td.Table;
TMSQuery1.ParamByName('Par2').AsInteger:=2019;
TMSQuery1.ParamByName('Par3').AsInteger:=4605;
```

Everything is working fine except for one specific SQL Server.
Here is execution from Profiler for this server. (*Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit))*

```
declare @p3 dbo.ut_Type1
insert into @p3 values('001','112',142)

exec sp_executesql N'exec dbo.p_Procedure1 @Table = @P1, @Year = @P2, @ID = @P3', N'@P1 dbo.ut_Type1,@P2 int,@P3 int',@p3,2019,4605
```

And getting error

> **"The table-valued parameter @P1 must be declared with the READONLY option"**

I've tried the same call on similar SQL Server(*Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64) 
Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit))*. Here is execution from Profiler

```
declare @p3 dbo.ut_Type1
insert into @p3 values('001','112',142)

exec sp_executesql N'exec dbo.p_Procedure1 @Table = @P1, @Year = @P2, @ID = @P3', N'@P1 dbo.ut_Type1 READONLY,@P2 int,@P3 int',@p3,2019,4605
```

And didn't get error.

The only differenece is  keyword READONLY that is missing on the first server table-valued parameter.

**Is there any configuration to SQL Server that I have to set?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is the procedure code the same on both servers?

Comment: Hi xyz. You need to end up with the READONLY specification on the parameter type specification in the call to sp_executesql.

Comment: @SeanLange 
Both stored procedures and client app are the same

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation Table Parameters have the following restrictions:

- SQL Server does not maintain statistics on columns of table-valued parameters.
- Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY parameters to Transact-SQL routines. You cannot perform DML operations such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT on a table-valued parameter in the body of a routine.
- You cannot use a table-valued parameter as target of a SELECT INTO or INSERT EXEC statement. A table-valued parameter can be in the FROM clause of SELECT INTO or in the INSERT EXEC string or stored procedure.